# How to suppress LivePass console messages? (Vimeo player)

Tags: javascript, vimeo

Vimeo uses a technology called LivePass in its embeddable video player.  It spits a *lot* of junk out to the console, and I'd like to mute this.  How can I change logging settings / suppress logs coming from LivePass?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome, in the Developer Console, to the left of the error is a little red circle with a "x".  Right click on that, and there is an option in the context menu to filter error messages from the script that is generating them.  That got rid of it.  I have had a lot of problems with Vimeo lately on my website.  I hope it improves.